# Create version mobile for wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a absolute page for mobile on wordpress theme.

About detecting mobile and tablet, I have done.

How can I redirect to subfolder or file for mobile when I use mobile or tablet.

Thanks all.

Comment: What have you tried? Which steps have you followed to redirect to the mobile page?

Comment: No. I don't want to redirect or change URL.

Comment: How to write htaccess to redirect folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are 2 ways to redirect to mobile subdirectory :

1) Simplest and easiest :

Use following javascript , place this at start of your html page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
  if (screen.width <= 800) {
    window.location = "http://m.domain.com";
  }
  //-->


</script>
```

2) A bit complex editing .htaccess file :

```
# Check for mime types commonly accepted by mobile devices
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml" [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^ http://m.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

tis rewrite your URL to mobile subdirectory.

Comment: I don't want to script becaue of SEO.

Comment: How to redirect of load folder don't change URL :( ?

Comment: @Vu  url can be used to redirect to a specific path . you can change url and which leads you to your sub folder !

Comment: FOR example if you have directory structure like  : u have a website folder and then you have 2 folders FORWEB and FORMOBILE . then use url redirect as http://website/FORWEB or http://website/FORMOBILE

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for that.

I write code in functions of wordpress theme.

```
if(!is_admin()){
//This file help us detect mobile base on user agent.
require_once ('mobile_detect.php');
$mobile_detect  = new Mobile_Detect();

function load_mobile() {
    if(is_home())
        $template_name = get_home_template();
    elseif(is_page())
        $template_name = get_page_template();
    elseif(is_single()) {
        $post_type = get_post_type() !== 'post'?'-'.get_post_type():'';
        $template_name = 'single'.$post_type.'.php';
    } elseif (is_archive()) {
        $archive_type = get_query_var('term');
        $template_name = get_template_directory().'/archive'.$archive_type.'.php';
    }
    $template_name = str_replace('.php', '', $template_name);
    return $template_name.'-sp.php';
}

if($mobile_detect->isMobile())
    add_filter('template_include', 'load_mobile');
}
```

That coding will load mobile version file (*-sp.php) when I access website.

That coding is not good. I'm trying to get name of file will be included. But I can't now.